# How to Reload/Refresh page in IE browsers without pop-up of form resubmission using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, popup

Iam reloading the page but it asking me for form re-submission confirmation which should not appear or is not expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was any form data posted on the referring page then you will always get that popup when you do a page refresh.  What you can do instead is set the page location to the current page location, which has a similar effect but is not a page refresh...

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this after form submission.

```
window.location.reload(true);
```